# supervisord failed to start nagiosapi after reboot, need to run reload manually

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze, nagios, supervisord

I have supervisord to start nagiosapi everytime the server starts. The API created a status dump file called status.dat, which will get updated periodically. The following is the conf file that starts the api.

```
[program:nagapi]
directory = /home/nagapi
user = api
command = /bin/bash -c "source /home/nagapi/.virtualenvs/nagapi/bin/activate;    /home/nagapi/nagios-api/nagios-api"
stdout_logfile = /home/nagapi/supervisor_nagios-api_stdout.log
stderr_logfile = /home/nagapi/supervisor_nagios-api_stderr.log
```

Everytime i restart the server, supervisord cannot start the api. stderr.log claims that it cannot find the status.dat file located in /var/cache/nagios3.

It seems like the files was not created yet when supervisor tried to run the api the first time. I'm saying this because if i do a supervisorctl reload, everything would reload just fine, and the api would run ok about 50 seconds after the reload command completes.

should i change the command option of the conf file to check for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I finally figured this out. Depending on how many servers you are monitoring, it might take some time for status.dat to be available upon restart. All I have to do is to wait until the file becomes available. I did so by adding **startsecs** option in my supervisor config file for the API. in my case, 60 seconds seem to do it.

If you are interested to know the details, I documented this problem in [my blog](http://digitallibraryworld.com/?p=291).